# How to get Cartesian product (combinatorial expansion) of name lists in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, cartesian-product

Using GNU-make, say that I have two lists in my Makefile, and I want to combine them to get their [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) as another list, so that I can use it as a list of targets.

As an example from a different language that I know better, [R has a function expand.grid()](http://scs.math.yorku.ca/index.php/R/Predict_with_expand.grid) which could accomplish this.

I actually figured out a way to do this using a Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all

prefix := 1 2

base := A B 

add_prefix = $(addsuffix $(base), $(prefix))

Obj = $(foreach base, $(base), $(add_prefix))

all: 
    @echo $(Obj)
```

But, this is pretty hacky and doesn't use the addsuffix function in an intuitive way. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not just do it in two loops?

```
obj := $(foreach X,$(prefix),$(foreach Y,$(base),$X$Y))
```